# How to make coq simplify expressions inside an implication hypothesis

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

Im trying to prove the following lemma:

```
Inductive even : nat → Prop :=
| ev_0 : even 0
| ev_SS (n : nat) (H : even n) : even (S (S n)).

Lemma even_Sn_not_even_n : forall n,
    even (S n) <-> not (even n).
Proof.
  intros n. split.
  + intros H. unfold not. intros H1. induction H1 as [|n' E' IHn].
    - inversion H.
    - inversion_clear H. apply IHn in H0. apply H0.
  + unfold not. intros H. induction n as [|n' E' IHn].
    -
Qed.
```

Here is what I got at the end:

```
1 subgoal (ID 173)

H : even 0 -> False
============================
even 1
```

I want coq to evaluate "even 0" to true and "even 1" to false. I tried `simpl`, `apply ev_0 in H.` but they give an error. What to do?

Comment: You haven't shown us the definition of `even`.

Comment: @Perry Added the definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Answer to the title

```
simpl in H.
```

### Real answer

**The above code will not work.**

The definition of `even` from the Logical Foundations book is:

```
Inductive even : nat → Prop :=
| ev_0 : even 0
| ev_SS (n : nat) (H : even n) : even (S (S n)).
```

`even 0` is a Prop, not a bool. Looks like you're mixing up the types `True` and `False` and the booleans `true` and `false`. They're totally different things, and not interchangeable under Coq's logic. In short, **`even 0` does not simplify to `true` or `True` or anything. It is just `even 0`.** If you want to show `even 0` is logically true, you should construct a value of that type.

I don't remember which tactics are available at that point in LF, but here are some possibilities:

```
(* Since you know `ev_0` is a value of type `even 0`,
   construct `False` from H and destruct it.
   This is an example of forward proof. *)
set (contra := H ev_0). destruct contra.

(* ... or, in one step: *)
destruct (H ev_0).

(* We all know `even 1` is logically false,
   so change the goal to `False` and work from there.
   This is an example of backward proof. *)
exfalso. apply H. apply ev_0.
```